Problem sending audio data to Google Speech To Text API with ReactJS
I'm working on a project that does real-time audio analysis. The first chunk sent after pressing the Start button always gives the output "Final Transcription:", but the subsequent ones give the output "No speech detected in audio". Also, if I press the stop button and then press start again, the above happens again. I'm using MediaRecorder.jsx to record users voice on another page and it works fine.  I tried to fix it with AI but it got more complicated. Please help me.
My code
import { LiveAudioVisualizer } from "react-audio-visualize";
import { useMediaRecorder } from "./MediaRecorder";

const Visualizer = () => {
  const {
    mediaRecorder,
    isRecording,
    startRecording,
    stopRecording,
    recordedChunks,
    resetRecording,
  } = useMediaRecorder();
  const [isSpeaking, setIsSpeaking] = useState(false);
  const [transcription, setTranscription] = useState("");
  const [accumulatedChunks, setAccumulatedChunks] = useState([]);
  const transcriptionRef = useRef("");
  const lastChunkRef = useRef(null);
  const resetIntervalRef = useRef(null);
  const lastSentTimestamp = useRef(Date.now());

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mediaRecorder && mediaRecorder.state === "recording") {
      setIsSpeaking(true);
    } else {
      setIsSpeaking(false);
    }
  }, [mediaRecorder]);

  // Reset recording every 30 seconds
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isRecording) {
      resetIntervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
        resetRecording();
      }, 30000);
    }

    return () => {
      if (resetIntervalRef.current) {
        clearInterval(resetIntervalRef.current);
      }
    };
  }, [isRecording, resetRecording]);

  // Handle new chunks
  useEffect(() => {
    if (recordedChunks.length > 0) {
      const lastChunk = recordedChunks[recordedChunks.length - 1];

      if (lastChunk !== lastChunkRef.current && lastChunk.size > 0) {
        console.log("New chunk received:", {
          size: lastChunk.size,
          time: new Date().toISOString(),
          totalChunks: accumulatedChunks.length,
        });

        setAccumulatedChunks((prev) => [...prev, lastChunk]);
        lastChunkRef.current = lastChunk;
      }
    }
  }, [recordedChunks]);

  // Handle transcription
  useEffect(() => {
    const sendAudioForTranscription = async () => {
      if (accumulatedChunks.length > 0) {
        const audioBlob = new Blob(accumulatedChunks, {
          type: "audio/webm;codecs=opus",
        });

        if (audioBlob.size === 0) {
          console.log("Empty audio blob, skipping");
          return;
        }

        const currentTimestamp = Date.now();
        if (currentTimestamp - lastSentTimestamp.current < 2000) {
          console.log("Skipping request due to rate limit");
          return;
        }

        lastSentTimestamp.current = currentTimestamp;

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("audio", audioBlob);

        try {
          const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/transcribe", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
          });

          const data = await response.json();
          if (data.transcription) {
            transcriptionRef.current += " " + data.transcription;
            setTranscription(transcriptionRef.current.trim());
            setAccumulatedChunks([]); // Clear only after successful transcription
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Transcription error:", error);
        }
      }
    };

    const transcriptionInterval = setInterval(() => {
      sendAudioForTranscription();
    }, 2000);

    return () => clearInterval(transcriptionInterval);
  }, [accumulatedChunks]);

  return (
    <div className="container mt-5 poppins-regular">
      <div className="row justify-content-center mb-4">
        <div className="col-auto">
          <button
            className="btn btn-primary me-2"
            onClick={startRecording}
            disabled={isRecording}
          >
            Start Recording
          </button>
          <button
            className="btn btn-danger"
            onClick={stopRecording}
            disabled={!isRecording}
          >
            Stop Recording
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* Transcription Display */}
      {transcription && (
        <div className="row justify-content-center mb-4">
          <div className="col-auto">
            <div className="card p-3">
              <h5 className="card-title">Transcription:</h5>
              <p className="card-text">{transcription}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
      {/* Speaker Status Display */}
      {isRecording && (
        <div className="row justify-content-center mb-4">
          <div className="col-auto">
            <p className="mb-1">
              Status:{" "}
              <strong>{isSpeaking ? "Person 1 is speaking" : "Silence"}</strong>
            </p>
            <p className="mb-1">
              Subject: <strong>Car</strong>
            </p>
            <p className="mb-1">
              Emotional State: <strong>Happy</strong>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}

      {/* Your existing visualization component */}
      {mediaRecorder && (
        <div className="row justify-content-center">
          <div className="col-auto">
            <LiveAudioVisualizer
              mediaRecorder={mediaRecorder}
              width={500}
              height={200}
              barColor="rgba(2, 21, 86, 1)"
              minDecibels={-85}
              smoothingTimeConstant={0.3}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Visualizer;
import React, { useState, useRef, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";

const useMediaRecorder = () => {
  const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState(false);
  const [recordedChunks, setRecordedChunks] = useState([]);
  const mediaRecorderRef = useRef(null);
  const streamRef = useRef(null);

  const setupRecorder = async () => {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: {
        channelCount: 1,
        sampleRate: 48000,
      },
    });

    streamRef.current = stream;

    const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
      mimeType: "audio/webm;codecs=opus",
      bitsPerSecond: 128000,
    });

    recorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
      if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
        setRecordedChunks((prev) => [...prev, event.data]);
      }
    };

    return recorder;
  };

  const resetRecording = useCallback(async () => {
    if (mediaRecorderRef.current) {
      mediaRecorderRef.current.stop();
      streamRef.current?.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
      setRecordedChunks([]);

      const newRecorder = await setupRecorder();
      mediaRecorderRef.current = newRecorder;
      newRecorder.start(2000);
    }
  }, []);

  const startRecording = async () => {
    try {
      const recorder = await setupRecorder();
      mediaRecorderRef.current = recorder;
      recorder.start(2000);
      setIsRecording(true);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("MediaRecorder error:", err);
    }
  };

  const stopRecording = useCallback(() => {
    if (mediaRecorderRef.current && isRecording) {
      mediaRecorderRef.current.stop();
      streamRef.current?.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
      setIsRecording(false);
      setRecordedChunks([]);
    }
  }, [isRecording]);

  return {
    isRecording,
    startRecording,
    stopRecording,
    recordedChunks,
    mediaRecorder: mediaRecorderRef.current,
    resetRecording,
  };
};

export { useMediaRecorder };
const express = require("express");
const speech = require("@google-cloud/speech");
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();
const upload = multer();
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());

const credentials = require(path.join(
  __dirname,
  "../cred.json"
));
const speechClient = new speech.SpeechClient({ credentials });

app.post("/transcribe", upload.single("audio"), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (!req.file) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "No audio file provided" });
    }

    console.log("Received audio size:", req.file.buffer.length);

    // Smaller buffer size limit
    // if (req.file.buffer.length > 100000) {
    //   return res.json({ transcription: "çok büyük" });
    // }

    const audioBytes = req.file.buffer.toString("base64");

    const config = {
      encoding: "WEBM_OPUS",
      sampleRateHertz: 48000,
      languageCode: "en-US",
      model: "default",
      enableAutomaticPunctuation: true,
      useEnhanced: true,
      enableWordConfidence: true,
      enableWordTimeOffsets: true,
      maxAlternatives: 1,
    };

    const audio = {
      content: audioBytes,
    };

    const request = {
      config,
      audio,
    };

    console.log("Sending request to Google Speech API");
    const [response] = await speechClient.recognize(request);
    console.log("Raw response:", response);
    if (!response.results || response.results.length === 0) {
      console.log("No speech detected in audio");
      return res.json({ transcription: "" });
    }

    let transcription = "";
    response.results.forEach((result) => {
      const alternative = result.alternatives[0];
      if (alternative.confidence > 0.8) {
        transcription += alternative.transcript + " ";
      }
    });

    console.log("Final transcription:", transcription.trim());
    return res.json({ transcription: transcription.trim() });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("API Error:", error);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});

module.exports = app;

const PORT = 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});


